# Animating SPA States with Vue

Tags: vue.js

So I have an active Vue.js SPA. I want to animate the transitions between each 'page'. I have the router wrapped in the transition tag like so:

```
          <transition name="example">
              <router-view></router-view>
          </transition>
```

I then apply some css like so:

```
    .example-enter, .example-leave-to{
        opacity:0;
    }

    .example-leave, .example-enter-to{
        opacity:1;
    }

    .example-enter-active, .example-leave-active{
        transition: opacity 500ms;
    }
```

What this does though, is it fades in the view, but when it exists, the new view comes up from the bottom, rather than just fading out, and fading in. So what am I missing here? Is it because I wrapped the router-view in the transition tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.  on the example-leave, example-enter-to needs to be changed to opacity 0.

Comment: Also you should try to add the **mode** attribute to the transition. To make the leave animation runs first than the enter one.